# Thread deadlock with play 2.2.1 and JPA

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

I find some strange behavior with JPA. In some case we got an error

```
 "Timed out waiting for a free available connection."
 at com.jolbox.bonecp.DefaultConnectionStrategy.getConnectionInternal(DefaultConnectionStrategy.java:88) ~[bonecp.jar:na]
```

Source for that line available at: https://github.com/wwadge/bonecp/blob/master/bonecp/src/main/java/com/jolbox/bonecp/DefaultConnectionStrategy.java#L88

I did the simple research and found this:

1. Play2 uses actor model with akka.
2. Play2 uses bonecp for database connection pool.
3. For process @Transaction request Play2 uses at least 2 separate actors:

   One actor for get connection from pool and process the call.

   Relevant code:

   - https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-java-jpa/src/main/java/play/db/jpa/TransactionalAction.java
   - https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-java-jpa/src/main/java/play/db/jpa/JPA.java#L180
   - https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/core/j/JavaAction.scala#L61

   Second actor for commit or rollback transaction. Connection released at this moment.

   Relevant code:

   - https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-java-jpa/src/main/java/play/db/jpa/JPA.java#L185
4. Both actors are executed from one akka executor and thread pool. Look: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ThreadPools

   By default there are 24 threads.
5. By default 30 connections are avalible for bonecp pool. Look: docs at http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SettingsJDBC
   and code at https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-jdbc/src/main/scala/play/api/db/DB.scala#L372

Let's assume that we have a high load application that must process many concurrent requests. At my tests i have problems with 50+ concurrent requests for default configuration.
You can repeat my test and catch this problem with only 3 concurrent requests with non default configuration like this:

```
play {
  akka {
    akka.loggers = ["akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger", "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
   loglevel = DEBUG
    actor {
      default-dispatcher = {
        fork-join-executor {
         parallelism-factor = 1.0
          parallelism-min = 1
          parallelism-max = 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

...
db.default.minConnectionsPerPartition=2
db.default.maxConnectionsPerPartition=2
...
```

Complexity and processing time do not matter for this test. My processing time is like 7 ms (parsing params + one insert to database). You only need to send more  concurrent requests than connection pool size.
Now i write what i think is happening.

1. Many actors captured threads and connections for processing request.
2. Many actors trys to get connect from pool. But there are no free connections that available at this moment (all other actors captured them). This connection pool based on BlockingQueue. Code:
   https://github.com/wwadge/bonecp/blob/master/bonecp/src/main/java/com/jolbox/bonecp/DefaultConnectionStrategy.java#L82

   So current thread is blocked for a timeout at this line (one second by default).
3. If some threads are blocked by this actors then some actors can not be executed with this threads.
4. So less connections are returned to connection pool because less actors can be executed with less number of threads.
5. At some time all threads will be blocked. And there is not any threads available for execute actors that shall return connections to the pool.

That looks like deadlock.

Can someone give me an advice how can i avoid this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone give me an advice how can i avoid this problem ?

Avoid using Akka actors for directly making multiple simultaneous potentially-blocking requests to the same resource. Use a separate thread pool to do the JDBC stuff instead.

Comment: I cant avoid problem that way because that akka actors is a part of play2 framefork, my own code it pretty simple and do not run actors itself. May be some config can fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually none of your code is going through actors here, but it is passing between different threads.

You should configure your thread pools to be large, as recommended for Java apps doing blocking in this document:

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ThreadPools

Comment: after some research and tests i came to the conclusion that its a bug because cannot be fixed for sure by config but can be fixed by code change (using JPA.withTransaction manualy instead of using @Transactional annotation). I created issue  https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2208

Comment: i set parallelism-max to 60 and still got an error. I think that there is no way to fix it by config and we always get a chance that some actor will stuck on BlockingQueue if we set maxConnectionsPerPartition less than parallelism-max. Anyway we will get a problem in case that number of concurrent requests more than maxConnectionsPerPartition param.